# Implement a coin jar in C#

Tags: c#, oop, object

I have a general object oriented programming question.  It is from an assignment, and I have written my answer, but I doubt that its what the instructors are looking for.  I was looking for anyone's input and advice on what C# OOP techniques to use to implement the class properly.

**Question:**
Implement a coin jar in C#. The coin jar will only accept US coinage and has a volume of 32 fluid ounces. Additionally, the jar has a counter to keep track of the total amount of money collected and has the ability to reset the count back to $0.00

**My Code:**

```
interface ICoinJar
{
    int coinage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    void resetcount();
}


static class USCoinTypes
{
 //Might want to make this a static array.
    public static readonly int US_CURRENCY_TYPE = 1;
    public static readonly int CURRENCY_AMOUNT = 0;
    public static readonly int CURRENCY_VOLUME = 1;
    public static readonly int MAX_VOLUME = 32;

    public enum CoinTypes
    {
        ONE_CENT = 0,
        FIVE_CENT,
        TEN_CENT,
        TWENTY_FIVE_CENT
    }

    public static readonly int[,] CoinInfo =
    {
        //amount, volume
        {1,5},
        {5,6},
        {10,3},
        {25,8}
    };

}


class USCoinJar : ICoinJar 
{

    // coinage in cents (NOT $)
    public int coinage { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }

    public USCoinJar()
    {
    }

    //in Cents.
    //Could also make this accept an array for inserting multiple coins.
    public bool addcoins(int amount, int volume,  USCoinTypes.CoinTypes currencytype)
    {
        if (this.volume + volume > USCoinTypes.MAX_VOLUME)
            return false;
        coinage = coinage + amount;
        this.volume = this.volume + volume;
        return true;
    }

    public void resetcount()
    {
        coinage = 0;
        volume = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: The US coin names for the values you have are penny (one cent), nickel (five cent), dime (ten cent), and quarter (twenty-five cent), and you're missing the 50 cent (half-dollar) and $1.00 (dollar) coins as well.

Comment: What is your question? Is it not working properly? Do you simply want someone to review your code? You can try [code review .SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that. Additionally, I would make your coin information in to classes (ICoin, Penny, Nickel, etc.) rather than a bunch of static stuff. Lose the arrays as well, that's just unnecessary clutter.

Comment: You aren't really asking a question here, you are just dumping your code and asking us to fix it. I provided some general notes below, but really you should probably speak to your professor if this is the farthest you were able to get.

Comment: Do you really think that this is solution? Main challenge of this task is to implement algorythm of placing coins of known diamater (can see on wikipedia) at bottom of jar, that is round too.

Comment: I think the interviewer is asking this question for testing the data structure skill.You can implement this by using stack.

Answer (score 3):

Few problems with your implementation:

- You are exposing both coinage and volume as writtable, meaning I can say `coinage = 100000; volumne = 0;` and your program will continue as if nothing was wrong.
- You are requiring the user to calculate volume, don't make your user do math you can do
- You aren't actually allowing the user to tell you enough information to calculate volume. If I call addcoins with and amount of 25 cents, does that mean a quarter, 25 pennies, a nickel, etc.
- What are the `static readonly int` values for, and why would you make them an array?
- Naming, unless your professor said otherwise, you should follow the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) put out by Microsoft.

I could go on, but this is hopefully enough to get you started on looking properly at what your real requirements are and how you are going to satisfy them.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the help.  Will try again and post it.